# Spring-Boot 1.4.0 Working with random ports Example

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

i want to write my first spring-boot 1.4.0 integration tests. But the Example on Spring Docs doesn't work for me. Maybe anyone can help me :)

If i want to run the Example Test, i get the following error:

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext 
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) 
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) 
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:49) 
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) 
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) 
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. 
    Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy. 
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) 
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) 
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ... 27 more
```

My Test Class:

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.*;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.*;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Test
    public void testExample() throws Exception {
        String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/api/label/language/DE", String.class);
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("Hello World");
    }
}
```

SpringBootApplication:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication()
@Import(value = {CassandraDataSource.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Docs from Spring (40.3.3 Working with random ports):
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: I think problem comes in your test because you didn't specify your Application class. **@SpringApplicationConfiguration(
        classes=Application.class)** , try adding this annotation in your test class.

Comment: @duardito Typically, that shouldn't be necessary. @Merth92 what packages are `Application` and `ControllerTest` in?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson There are in the same package.

Comment: @duratio if i add the annotation i get another error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.test.context.MergedContextConfiguration.getContextCustomizers()Ljava/util/Set;

 at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.createModifiedConfig(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:277)
 at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:119)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration ..

Comment: @Merth92 That `NoSuchMethodError` suggests that your classpath is messed up. `getContextCustomizers` is new in Spring Framework 4.3 (which is what Spring Boot 1.4 requires). Perhaps you need to tell IDEA to update/refresh your project?

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson still not working... I will try in a clean new Project.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance problem in SpringBootApplication: Application.class

Put instead of:

```
SpringApplication.run(CfanApplication.class, args);
```

Following:

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

Comment: Sorry, im only removed the name and forgot this line.

Comment: I corrected my mistake in the question. Thanks for the hint!